# How to retrieve the data from Sage Evolution Using flowgear Integration

Tags: flowgear

I was working with Flowgear-Sage Evolution Integration.I can able to create the Orders & Accounts and other services in sage evolution using flowgear node.But I cannot find the relevant node for retrieving the Accounts or Order based on some input.Please help me out doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On connectors which we have access to the database, we use a [SQL Query](http://developers.flowgear.net/kb/Node:SQL_Query) to read from the product, and use the connector to write to the product.

You will use the same SQL details on the `SQL Query` connector as you did on the Sage Evolution connector.

The accounts table is called `Clients`, the order header is `InvNum`, and the order detail is `_btblInvoiceLines`.

The `AutoIndex` on `InvNum` links to `iInvoiceID` on `_btblInvoiceLines`.

Answer (score 1):

I have shared the demo flowgear workflow for how to get sage evolution database data.
I hope it is used full for you.
In this workflow i have get sage client data and sent to web API.

Sage evolution database you can used,

1)Client for account mapping

2)InvNum for sage Document module mapping.

See the flowgear workflow link:
http://flowgear.me/s/JWTcGJp